# Select All Checkbox scope variable not getting set

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to implement the functionality of "select All" checkbox should get selected when we select all the sub-items.

`Plnkr`Here is the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/h8sNbpVZT0eUUn02PTZo?p=preview).

why the "select All" model is not getting set?

Comment: you have `ng-click` and `ng-change` on one checkbox. They are fighting with each other. Use only one handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `select` method to this:

```
$scope.select = function(){
    angular.forEach($scope.friends, function (item) {
        if(!item.Selected){ // uncheck 'all' if any item is not selected
            $scope.selectedAll = false;
        }
    });
};
```

**UPDATE**

You can remove the `select` method entirely, 'check all' is handled in the `isSelected` method.

Comment: @Aparna, looks like you can remove the 'select' method at all.